Play Games Platform works development build but don't works release built
encountered an error in a game I've been working on for a long time, and unfortunately the solutions I searched on "Google" didn't work or I couldn't manage it.
about the problem;
The game somehow cannot connect to the "android games platform". The interesting thing is that if I build the game in development mode, I do not experience any problems, it works perfectly fine. but if I configure it in release mode the game will run "PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();" It gets stuck in its code and does not continue.
So how do I know this: When I replace this code, the previous codes work.
As for detailed information:
The Unity version I use is: 2022.3.5f1.
The error I get from android logcat:

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames,
Unity java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames,
Error Unity at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method).

etc...
Part of the code I wrote:
public void Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(FirstDoorsOpening()); // this is the game opening      
}
IEnumerator FirstDoorsOpening()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate(); // This was normally at the start
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
    SignIn();
}
public void SignIn()
{   
     PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
}
internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
{
    if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        AuthenticationSuccess();
   }
    else
    {          
    detailsText_Negative.text = "SIGN IN FAILED  PLEASE CHECK YOUR CONNECTION";
    }
}
void AuthenticationSuccess()
{
    StartCoroutine(GotoFirstScene());
}

Other details you may need:
Google play games plugin dependencies:  <repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>
strip
If there is any other detail you would like, please let me know.
